# How to dynamically create runtime controls in ASP.NET Webforms using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've a table in a database  with this structure:

- field_order
- field_label
- field_name
- field_type
- width
- height

I want to loop through all rows and create controls in my page, putting them in classic table 2 columns x X rows (each row a control).

This is my server side code:

```
using (MySqlConnection db = new MySqlConnection(myAppConnectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE idtemplate =" + templateID.ToString() + " ORDER BY field_order";

    MySqlDataReader dr;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,db);

    db.Open();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string field_label = dr["field_label"].ToString();
            string field_name  = dr["field_name"].ToString();
            string field_type = dr["field_type"].ToString();
            string field_width = dr["width"].ToString();
            string field_height = dr["height"].ToString();

            switch (field_type)
            {
                case "Text":
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = field_label;
                    lbl.ID = "lbl" + field_name;
                    panelFields.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.Text = "";
                    txt.ID = "txt" + field_name;

                    Unit ut = new Unit(field_width);
                    txt.Width = ut;
                    ut = new Unit(field_height);
                    txt.Height = ut;

                    panelFields.Controls.Add(txt);
                    break;

                case "Number":
                    break;

                case "Date":
                    break;

                case "Time":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using `panelFields.Controls.Add(myControl)` I add each controls in a panel but next to each other.

My questions are:

1. How can I add controls in a table 2 columns x N rows ?
2. If I add controls in this way, will it possible for me to access them from server side to save `TextBox` values ?

Thanks

Comment: You seemed to figure out #1, and then #2 is yes as well.  You'll need to use ````myPanel.FindControl```` with the ID.

Comment: Also, the ````<asp:PlaceHolder>```` is a good element to dynamically add controls to.  Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding "Literal" controls to myPanel with HTML Tag.

Like:

myPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(""));

myPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  "));

....

myPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(""));